# Sharing folders between VMs on ESXI 6.5 for backups

Tags: vmware-esxi, share

I'm new in the ESXI server, and I have a server my company has a few vms for applications (mostly linux with php, tomcat services and SQL Server services).

I have one datastore, of 4TB, I'd like to create a folder (or a vmdk) which I can share between a few VMs having SQL Server. I intend to make a backup of SQL and save those files in that shared folder. Which I'll eventually copy to an external place.

I've tried creating a vmdk, over a new  SCSI controller as LSI Logic SAS, and add the previously vmdk created, Sharing as multi-user, but it doesn't work as expected. First time I start my machines I'm able to see my files, but if I create another file in VM1, VM2 will only see those files after I reboot or remount the disk on linux.

There's any way to accomplish that need? Or am I just doing it wrong way?

I've considered install a SAMBA on a linux server, and share to the others VMs, but some SQL Server has files over 300GB, so the backup over network will take a long time.

Any help with this case?

Merry Chistmas and Happy new year for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys.

A friend managed with a solution. We created an VM with Freenas, and shared as a NFS to the VMs. Considering we have a 10Gbs network card, that should handle for now.

Thanks for the help and clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Using a folder on a VMFS volume is nothing an ESXi host supports - a VM guest cannot ever access a VMFS volume.[1]

A VMDK is a block device like a disk drive. Sharing it across VMs requires a clustering file system with coordinated access. Using a normal file system will quickly corrupt the volume due to concurrent, uncoordinated access.

Of course, you can assign a VMDK to a guest and then use network file sharing (NFS, SMB, ...) for other guests to access. If the share doesn't provide enough performance you need to speed up the network (or the host, for a virtual network).

[1] That is unless you use the appropriate APIs, SFTP or such.

Answer (score 0):

Use a backup solution that is aware of your VMs. A proper backup solution will create a snapshot of your VM, mount the snapshot read-only to create the backup and delete the snapshot afterwards.